# Can't set user data after firebase auuthentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a react app on firebase. The issue that fire store doesn't set up `userdata` after fire authentication although it's been successfully authenticated on Google. Please help me if you have some clues to solve that. And I can't get error texts here.

```
  login = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithRedirect(provider)
      .then(result => {
        const user = result.user;
        const userRef = firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user.uid);

        userRef.get().then(function(doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("User data:", doc.data());
          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            userRef.set({
              uid: user.uid,
              name: user.displayName,
              photoURL: user.photoURL
            });
          }
        });
      });

    this.props.history.push("/");
  };
```

#### Additional

```
'user' is not defined.
'userRef' is not defined
```

I have tried the code. But user and userRef could not be defined here:

```
    if (doc.exists) {
      console.log("Doc for user " + user.uid + " already exists");
      throw new Error("Doc for user " + user.uid + " already exists");
    } else {
      return userRef.set({
        uid: user.uid,
        name: user.displayName,
        photoURL: user.photoURL
      });
    }
```

#### Additional 2

I don't know why but that would not work `then` on Firebase Authentication.

```
login = () => {
  let user;
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithRedirect(provider)
    .then(result => {
      console.log("result", result);
      // result has been skipped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the [`signInWithRedirect()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#sign-inwith-redirect) method returns a promise with no return value (i.e. `Promise<void>`). Therefore doing

```
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithRedirect(provider)
      .then(result => {...});
```

will not work.

You need to use the [`getRedirectResult()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#getredirectresult) method, as explained in the doc:

> Authenticates a Firebase client using a full-page redirect flow. To
>   handle the results and errors for this operation, refer to
>   `firebase.auth.Auth.getRedirectResult`.

Therefore, in your `login` function, you should just have two lines:

```
  login = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithRedirect(provider);
  }
```

And somewhere else in your code (I don't know exactly where as I don't know reactjs...) you need to have the following code (note how the different Promises are [chained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining)):

```
    let user;

    firebase
    .auth()
    .getRedirectResult()
    .then(result => {
        user = result.user;
        const userRef = firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid);

        return userRef.get();
      })
      .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log('Doc for user ' + user.uid + ' already exists');
          throw new Error('Doc for user ' + user.uid + ' already exists');
        } else {
          return doc.ref.set({
            uid: user.uid,
            name: user.displayName,
            photoURL: user.photoURL
          });
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.history.push('/');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.props.history.push('/errorPage');
      });
```

---

Note that in case several users are able to sign-in with the same Google Account, you may need to use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) when checking the non-existence of the doc at `userRef`.

Comment: Thank you so much @renaud-tarnec

But that would not work because the code after getting doc have no userRef and user data.

          return userRef.set({
            uid: user.uid,
            name: user.displayName,
            photoURL: user.photoURL
          });


User and userRef are not defined. How to define?

Comment: Do you mean that in the `then()` after `userRef.set({...})` you want to use `user.data`? Or `user.uid`? Can you give more detail on what you exactly want to do?

Comment: Thanks I have added to my question description.

Comment: Oh I see now! Indeed there was a mistake, I had not tested the code.... I've adapted the answer, it should be ok now. Tell me if it works!

Comment: Hey Renaud. I really appreciate your help :) And I have tried to get run again and again, but this could not run functions after `then`.

Comment: @k10a I've written a totally new answer! I took the time to analyse and thoroughly test it. It works form me in a "pure" JavaScript page. You should not have too many difficulties to adapt it to reactjs!

Comment: Thanks I totally got it!